# Unable to access nested object after Angular 8 upgrade

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I had an Angular 2 app and decided to upgrade to Angular 8 (haven't previously worked with anything newer than 2).

In one case I have a dialog component with a dynamically loaded internal content component, but the content component is not receiving variables assigned to it. These were formerly accessible on `ngOnInit`, let alone `ngAfterViewInit`, but now they aren't.

Here is some example code for the final (content component) object:

```
public params: ContentParams;
public isDataValid = true;
public error = '';

constructor() {
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
    const o = this;
    const t = setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(o.params); // works
    }, 500);
    console.log(this.params); // undefined
}
```

And here is the parent (dialog component) creation + assignment of params to the content component:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const factory = this._componentResolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.contentComponentType);
    this._dialogContentComponent = this.contentContainerRef.createComponent(factory).instance as IDialogContentComponent<any, any>;
    this._changeDetectorRef.detectChanges(); // necessary change for the dialog component to appear

    if (this._dialogConfig.contentParams) {
        this._dialogContentComponent.params = this._dialogConfig.contentParams;
    }
}
```

Is there a different lifecycle event in the content component that I need to subscribe to? Or is this just not a correct way of doing things in newer versions of Angular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this kind of scenarios, I am preferring to use subjects

Add a subject in one shared service and then share the state between your components or services.

#### A shared service

```js
@Injectable()
export class SharedService {

  public params$: Subject<any> = new Subject();

  constructor() { }

}
```

#### Update

```js
constructor(private _sharedService: SharedService) {
    this._sharedService.params$.next({test: 1})
}
```

#### Subscribe

```js
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { SharedService } from './shared.service';


interface ContentParams {}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {

  public params: ContentParams;
  public isDataValid = true;
  public error = '';

  constructor(private _sharedService: SharedService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._sharedService.params$.subscribe( params => {
      console.log(params) // {test: 1}
      this.params = params;
    });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your **AfterViewInit()** will fire when this link finishes executing, so you won't have **params** loaded yet by the time its called. That is why the **setTimeout()** works.

```
this._dialogContentComponent = this.contentContainerRef.createComponent(factory).instance as IDialogContentComponent<any, any>;
```

You could harness the power of RxJS to help (Don't forget the unsubscribe part):

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

export class Something {
    public params: ContentParams;
    public isDataValid = true;
    public error = '';
    public params$ = new Subject();

    constructor() {
        this.params$.subscribe((value) => {
            this.params = value;
        });
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        const o = this;
        const t = setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(this.params); // works
        }, 500);
        console.log(this.params); // undefined
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.params$.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Then instead of direct assignment, emit a new value:

```
if (this._dialogConfig.contentParams) {
    this._dialogContentComponent.params$.next(this._dialogConfig.contentParams);
}
```

https://www.learnrxjs.io/subjects/